# Selenium: I'm using a working xpath which doesn't work in my project

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am a student, and as part of a lab, I'm learning Selenium, where I'm trying to use xpath to find an element on a page
[For a test, I decided to take this google docs login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGs7C.png)

[For this page I created a working xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ607.png) -

```
//div[@class="CxRgyd"]//input[@type="email"]
```

But my code is throwing an exception -

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="CxRgyd"]//input[@type="email"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.99)
```

My code:

```
import time
import selenium as sl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = sl.webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.google.com/docs/about/')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "#hero-cta-wrapper > a.glue-button.glue-button--medium-emphasis").click() 
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="CxRgyd"]//input[@type="email"]').send_keys("aermilov756@gmail.com")
```

I will be grateful if you tell me how to make the code better, but first of all I want to understand why xpath does not work

python 3, pycharm, win10, chrome 108

Comment: We cannot log in to see the document you created, so there is no way for us to verify that your xpath is correct.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, forgot to remove the transition to a new page 
.New link:
https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S-402161615%3A1670632877042921&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fu%2F0%2F%3Ftgif%3Dd&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fu%2F0%2F%3Ftgif%3Dd&ltmpl=docs&osid=1&passive=1209600&service=wise&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AeAAQh54DIH1kd4WzXn-yGRiuiYPBlICyUUDpSrWrPxbDOOlEHwkT_DQn3L-uIGOx10qv2v4EDj1

Answer (score 0):

What if you try first to do click into the field? I tried this and it worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/?tgif=d&pli=1'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="CxRgyd"]//input[@type="email"]')
email.click()
email.send_keys("aermilov756@gmail.com")
```